# A minimal web editor for Rails applications

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, editor, wysiwyg

I am using Ruby on Rails 4 and I would like to add a text editor in my application, possibly a simpler and easier way. I plan to use it just for editing description content in my forms, so some features that I could need for editing the text are *italic*, **bold**, to add some [hyperlinks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperlink) and some basic customizable functionality as-like `blockquote`, maybe a "markup language" such that at Wikipedia, Github or Stackowrflow itself.

I am almost new to web editors but, for performance reasons, I am looking for a "minimal" / "light" / "not strong" editor. That is, for example, the editor should be:

- small-sized as possible;
- style free (at least for customizing the CSS template, if any);
- eventually without advanced features such image upload functionality (since I do not plan to use those).

Of course, it should be "integrable" with Rails 4 and compatible with the related jQuery 1.10.2 shipped with Rails itself.

*Note*: I seen many editors as-like [WYSIWYGs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wysiwyg) or [rich-text editors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rich-text-editor) but, maybe, the WYSIWYGs are not the best choose for my matters at all. I am still not sure what to choose.

Answer (score 3):

[CKeditor](http://ckeditor.com/) has been a quality editor for a number of years and does the job well

Have a look at https://github.com/tsechingho/ckeditor-rails it's quite unobtrusive, however 
requires JS to be enabled.

You can customize it quite easily by putting a simple config file in your assets folder where you can choose the tabs you want to use, for example:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = (config) ->
    config.uiColor = "#333333"
    ..... # other config options available
    config.toolbar=[ ['Cut','Copy','Paste','-','Undo','Redo','RemoveFormat','-','Link','Unlink','-','Table','HorizontalRule','SpecialChar'], '/' ]
```

Currently the released gem only works with Rails 3, however you can easily modify your gemfile to point to github instead of rubygems

Comment: What gem on Github (that is, what git URL) should I point to in my `Gemfile` in order to make the `CKeditor` to work with my Rails 4 application?

Comment: The master supports rails 4, it's just not been pushed to rubygems (last time I looked) so just `gem 'ckeditor_rails', :git => 'https://github.com/tsechingho/ckeditor-rails'` should work fine

Answer (score 0):

For your purpose there ia a lot js plugins. Most of them have minimal settings. Also you can to create own control (html helper).

Comment: Can you be more explicit in you answer (since I am almost new to web editors with Rails)? For example, can you link some JS plugins that are good for my purpose? or can you add a post relating how "to create own control (html helper)"?